# Twitter Bootstrap for ASP.Net MVC 4 - jQuery 1.9 and jQuery.Validate.js

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having an issue with the Twitter Bootstrap for ASP.Net MVC

```
Check out http://nuget.org/packages/twitter.bootstrap.mvc4
```

Using Visual Studio 2012, in a blank MVC 4 template, I have simply run the NuGet package installer for "Install-Package twitter.bootstrap.mvc4.sample", which includes "Install-Package twitter.bootstrap.mvc4" and jQuery 1.9 as a dependency.

Everything builds fine at compile time, but as soon as I debug the project I get a critical javascript error:

[jquery-1.9.0.min.map Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rn2tN.png)

```
JavaScript critical error at line 1, column 11 in http://localhost:10277/Scripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.map
SCRIPT1004: Expected ';'
```

If I continue then I keep getting javascript errors raised from the web browser virtually ANY time I try to interact with the webpage:

[jQuery.Validate.js Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wT7B6.png)

```
Unhandled exception at line 1152, column 5 in http://localhost:10277/Scripts/jquery.validate.js
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'call' of undefined or null reference
```

I can't replace jQuery 1.9 with an earlier version as nugget won't allow me to uninstall jQuery or add an earlier version over the top.

I've always been a string back end developer but kind of new to this front-end stuff. Trying to do this the right way, but seems like it's harder than it ought to be.

Any ideas? What should be my starting point?

Comment: I was only seeing this error in ie.. Jquery-migrate plugin resolved it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [jQuery migrate plugin](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.0.0.js)

Comment: Hey Arun

Thanks. It kind of helped in that it got rid of the error raised by the browser (the second one), but the first error, to do with the min.map still exists.

Thanks for the help. Any suggestions on the first issue are welcome.

Comment: Hmmm.... To fix the first issue, I've removed the offending .map file altogether. My understanding is that the map file is only used with the minified version of the library, so whilst debug = true there's no impact. I can still hit breakpoints in the javascript as I'm not referencing the minified version.